# post data usign an array from view to controller in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I wan to create below view in mvc with model binding in mvc [image]

Comment: What is your question? What are the things you have tried? If you are new to MVC check tutorials. Also there are many questions with same title you have (except the word array).

Comment: In PHP just submit data with an array from form and get it in $_Post but i am confused how i can achieve this in mvc with model binding

Comment: I assume you want to post data in C# MVC 5. In a  Post request, you can get the form data like Request.Form["date"] in controller action method. Here data is the name of an input element.